# Turning a painting into a .png file

Tags: transparency

I've been asked to scan one of my paintings and then turn it into a .png.  I don't have photoshop.  How might  do this with the regular programs on my PC?

Comment: It seems somewhat unlikely that png would be the preferred format for a painting by the way, although of course you might have a reason it HAS to a png (or it might be a low tone variation painting)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Photoshop to scan images, or to change file formats.  All scanners come with software for scanning, and you can use almost any image editor to open an image then save it as a PNG, even Microsoft Paint can do it.